# Calculating the possible values of momentum (and their associated probabilities) if the wavefuntion is not an eigenstate of the momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, superposition

I am working through some problems to practice for an upcoming quantum mechanics exam. I do not understand how, in general, one splits the resulting wavefunction of an operator which is not an eigenstate of that operator. The following question serves as a good example:

*A particle is in a quantum state with the projection to real space$$〈x|ψ〉≡ψ(x) =\sqrt{\frac{8}{3a}}cos^2(\frac{\pi x}{a}) $$(defined in the region $−a/2< x < a/2$). If a measurement of momentum is made on this particle, what possible values could be observed and with what probability?}*

Working with the momentum operator $\hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ you arrive at the wavefunction $$\frac{\hbar \pi}{2a}\sqrt{\frac{8}{3a}}(\exp(2\pi ix/a)-\exp(-2\pi ix/a))$$

The specifics are not important but the resulting wavefunction is not an eigenstate of the momentum operator. 
So my question is, in general how does one approach this problem?

My attempt was to define two states $$ψ_+ = \exp(2\pi i x/a)  $$
and $$ψ_- = \exp(-2\pi i x/a)  $$

These are both eigenstates of the momentum operator and allow us to rewrite the resulting wavefunction as a superposition of two momentum eigenstates. Would the possible momentum observables then just be the (normalized) constants in front of each of the states? I am assuming the probability would just be half for both as they are equal in magnitude - but in general how would this be solved?

Apologies if this is a duplicate but it was a little tricky to search! Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\cos^2(\pi x/a)$ is not a combination of your $\Psi_\pm$, the sum of which is proportional to $\cos(2\pi x/a)$.

Comment: I noticed that after writing it out - does that mean the method I used is invalid?

Comment: You need to expand your wavefunction in terms of normalized eigenstates of $\hat p$.  You certainly do not have the correct expansion.

Comment: You are almost correct.  The wave function is $\psi={1\over4}\sqrt{8\over3}(2\psi_0+\psi_++\psi_-)$  I’ll let you figure out what $\psi_0$ is.  Think about what <$\psi|\psi_{0,+,-}$> stands for to get probabilities.

Comment: The comment above assumes all $\psi$‘s are normalized.